# Adding psd file to an epub

Tags: epub, ibooks, psd

I have some psd files that I need to add in my epub for ipads. Is there a way to do it? Does epub support '.psd' files? If so, what will be the media-type that has to be added in the 'package.opf'?

The reason I need to add the psd files is that I need images with no background frame or with a transparent frame. I think its not possible to get a transparent frame in jpeg files and tiff files. Please advice.

Thanks in advance

Vignesh

Comment: Try saving the psd as a png, I think you'll get the results you want. There aren't too many applications that you can use a psd file in, unless it's an adobe product like dreamweaver or fireworks.

Answer (score 0):

No, PSD files are not supported. JPG, PNG, GIF, or SVG. That's it.

Comment: Also, you can have transparency in .PNG files, although not all readers honour it. iBooks, for example, will keep the transparency, but Kindle will display the transparent regions as white (which may or may not be what you want).